# PHP-DI is not working in integration with ZendFramework2

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, php-di

Could you please give a hint why [PHP-DI integration with Zend Framework 2](https://github.com/mnapoli/PHP-DI-ZF2) is not working for me (reproduced with Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 and Apache/2.2.22 (Win32) PHP/5.3.13).

**composer.json**:

```php
{
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "zendframework/zendframework": "2.3.5",
        "mnapoli/php-di": "4.4.6",
        "mnapoli/php-di-zf2": "0.3.0",
       ...
},
    ...
```

**config\application.config.php**:

```php
<?php
return array(
    'modules' => array(
        'Morpho',
        'DI\ZendFramework2',
    ),
    'module_listener_options' => array(
        'module_paths' => array(
            './module',
            './vendor',
        ),
    ),
);
?>
```

**module/Morpho/config.module.config.php**:

```php
<?php
return array(
    'service_manager' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            'DI\Container' => function() {
                $builder = new DI\ContainerBuilder();
                $builder->addDefinitionsFromFile("config/di.yml");
                return $builder->build();
            },
        ),
    ),
    'router' => array(
        ...
    ),
    'controllers' => array(
        ...
    ),
    'view_manager' => array(
        ...
    ),
);
```

**config/di.yml**:

```
Morpho\Service\PartOfSpeechService:
    class: Morpho\Service\PhpMorphyPartOfSpeechService
```

**module/Morpho/src/Morpho/Controller/PartOfSpeechController**:

```php
class PartOfSpeechController extends AbstractRestfulController {
    ...
    /**
     * @Inject
     * @var PartOfSpeechService
     */
    public $partOfSpeechService;

    public function processPostData(Request $request) {
        $partsOfSpeech = $this->partOfSpeechService->getPartsOfSpeech("test", "en_EN");
        return new JsonModel($partsOfSpeech);
    }
}
```

When running this code under apache each time I get:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Zend\ModuleManager\Exception\RuntimeException'
with message 'Module (DI\ZendFramework2) could not be initialized.' in \vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager.php:195
Stack trace:
0 \vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager.php(169): Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager->loadModuleByName(Object(Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleEvent))
1 \vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager.php(96): Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager->loadModule('DI\ZendFramewor...')
2 [internal function]: Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager->onLoadModules(Object(Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleEvent))
3 \vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(468):
call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleEvent))
4 \vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(207): Zend\EventM in \vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager.php on line 195
```

Any your thoughts would be really appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you just use zf2 Service Manager? http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.service-manager.quick-start.html

Comment: That's a very good question. Honestly saying I'm a very new to ZendFramework. I've discovered SM just recently. For me the DI approach used by PHP-DI (with annotations) looked much more close to Spring @Inject. That's why I stuck with it. I'll try to rewrite with SM and come back with the results here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For a service:**

factory config:

```
        'factories' => array(
            'MyService' => 'Application\Factory\MyService',
        ),
```

Factory class:

```
class MyService implements FactoryInterface
{

    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceManager)
    {
        $purifier = new MyService($serviceManager->get('MyAwesomeDependency'));
        return $purifier;
    }
}
```

**For a controller:**

ControllerFactory.php:

```
class PartOfSpeechControllerFactory
{
    public function __invoke($serviceLocator)
    {
        // Service locator here is the ControllerManager so get ServiceManager 
        $serviceManager = $serviceLocator->getServiceLocator();

        $controller = new PartOfSpeechController($serviceManager->get('PartOfSpeechService'));

        return $controller;
    }
}
```

class PartOfSpeechController.php

```
class PartOfSpeechController extends AbstractRestfulController {


    protected $partOfSpeechService;

    public function __construct(PartOfSpeechService $partOfSpeechService)
    {
         $this->partOfSpeechService = $partOfSpeechService;
    }


    public function processPostData(Request $request) {
         $var = $this->partOfSpeechService->serviceMethod();   
    }
}
```

The config for controller:

```
'factories' => array(
                'Application\Controller\PartOfSpeechController' => 'Application\Factory\PartOfSpeechControllerFactory'
        ),
```

Comment: A question, the usage of the service is still imply:

$serviceManager = $this->getServiceLocator();
$serviceManager->get("MyService")->doSmth();

Comment: The example is for a service but the config is basically the same for a controller

Comment: I have added another example, does that answer your question. The controller has no dependency on the locator only the factory

Comment: On a side note the code and functionality looks very similar to Zend\Di ... http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.di.introduction.html ... if you prefer container to locator perhaps you could try using that?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because you are using the old YAML syntax, but [since PHP-DI v4.0 the syntax is now PHP](http://php-di.org/news/06-php-di-4-0-new-definitions.html).

Head over to the documentation to learn about the syntax: http://php-di.org/doc/definition.html

Comment: Ah that makes sense now, tried to bugfix the issue in a vanilla install of zf2 with the provided op's config but couldn't quite work out the error.

Comment: I have to admit this is a weird edge case :/ Basically now that it is PHP config, the config file must return a PHP array. Here it's a YAML file, so when it's `include`d it will return null. PHP-DI then consider `null` as empty config, but it could show an error though that's a very weird situation IMO.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the suggestion given by Purple Hexagon and here is a **working** implementation using Service Manager:

**module/Morpho/config**:

```php
...
'service_manager' => array(
    'services' => array(
        "PartOfSpeechService" => new Morpho\Service\PhpMorphyPartOfSpeechService(),
    ),
),
...
```

**module/Morpho/src/Morpho/Controller/PartOfSpeechController.php**:

```php
class PartOfSpeechController extends AbstractRestfulController {
    ...
    public function processPostData(Request $request) {
        $serviceManager = $this->getServiceLocator();
        $partsOfSpeech = $serviceManager->get("PartOfSpeechService")->getPartsOfSpeech($request->getPost("phrase"),
                $request->getPost("language"));
        return new JsonModel($partsOfSpeech);
    }
}
```

Why I don't like this:

1. I have to use a "dummy" code to obtain serviceManager. That's "dummy" because that's not related to business logic of my application at all.
2. The Dependency Injection approach provided by ServiceManager makes my code dependent on the ServiceManager itself. Typically I should not care how a bean/object is injected and so shouldn't refer to any kind of container or ServiceManager in my code.

I think [PHP-DI](http://php-di.org/) is much more closer to the bean injection model used by Java Spring (that I believe is good). Unfortunately it is still not working for me.
And finally, the approach of obtaining object from container was working in PHP-DI as well.